Rewrite Rules - Rate limiting for certain files
So I created and added this block to my htaccess in order to rate limit Googlebot for non-xml (sitemap) files:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (Googlebot) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.xml$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{TIME_SEC} ^(0|6|12|18|24|30|36|42|48|54)$
RewriteRule ^ - [R=429,L]

As this is a WordPress site I also have the below in my htaccess:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

This works well other than the RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.xml$ [NC] line which was never triggering correctly and sitemaps were being 429'd
Now, I believed that putting my rate limiting before the WordPress rules would be best as otherwise the rate limiting would have index.php?page=etc for the Request URI, rather than the original URL?
After some trial and error a coworker moved the rate limiting to after the WordPress rules and magically that condition started working!
I'd love to know why this change actually fixes the issue at hand?
Is it related to the [L] flag present on the end of all of these rules?
Thanks in advance!

Are you sure it is actually working in both "directions"? Did you only check that you don't get a 429 response for the sitemap / .xml URLs any more; or did you also verify that you do get it for the other resources?
